# Constructing particular invariant subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

Suppose $Z$ is an endomorphism of an $N$-dimensional complex vector space $V$, and that $U \subset V$ is a $Z$-invariant subspace of codimension $M$. Suppose also that $Z$ admits a cyclic vector $\phi \in V$.

Now the minimal polynomial of $Z$ is a degree $N$ polynomial $f$ which factorizes as $f = g h$, where $h$ is the minimal polynomial of $Z\mid_U$, and $g$ has degree $M$.

Then $\ker h(Z) = U$, whilst $\ker g(Z) = W$ is another invariant subspace, of dimension $M$, which I am interested in. My question is: is there any other way to construct the space $W$, without mentioning minimal polynomials, and without making further assumptions about coprimality of $g,h$ or anything like that?

(In particular, note that as $g,h$ are not necessarily coprime, we cannot characterize $W$ by thinking about a $Z$-invariant complement to $U$.)